# Convert .ui to .py in Windows 10 cmd and using Anaconda

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, anaconda

similar questions have been asked before but none of the answers worked for me: I am trying to convert test.ui located in

```
C:\Users\johan\Desktop
```

to test.py using pyuic5.bat located in

```
c:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\
```

Should the conversion work with the following command-line?

```
"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat" -x "C:\Users\johan\Desktop.test.ui" -o test.py
```

This causes the following error message to pop up:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'
```

The same message pops up when I just write

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat
```

in the cmd. The code in pyuic5.bat is only one line and looks like this:

```
@C:/Program Files/Anaconda3\python.exe -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

I don't know what the code starting at -m means.

Thank you!

Comment: File names and file paths that have spaces in them must be quoted.  The file path to python.exe has a space in it.

Comment: Ok thank @Squashman it made it work! I just didn't expect to have to go into the Anaconda library and change things (I'm a beginner). Another question: After I made the change and write the same command line as above: "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat" -x "C:\Users\johan\Desktop.test.ui" -o test.py    an error pops up saying Error: Permission denied: "test.py"  , but it works when I go into the test.ui directory and do this which I thought was the same thing :   C:\Users\johan\Desktop>"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat" -x test.ui -o test.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the pyuic5.bat file in the Anaconda3 library from:

```
@C:/Program Files/Anaconda3\python.exe -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

to:

```
@"C:/Program Files/Anaconda3\python.exe" -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

and to run the conversion you should be in the directory of the .ui file

```
C:\Users\johan\Desktop>"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic5.bat" -x test.ui -o test.py
```

because for me at least it didn't work otherwise due to a permission error.